# How to send FormData from Node/Express to another application(Node/Express) using request

Tags: node.js, express, request, form-data, formidable

I have a frontend website *(ejs and node/express)* running on localhost:8000 (if this helps) and the backend server *(node/express)* running on localhost:8010 (p.s. my database is in the backend).
I am trying to implement Social login *(fb, google etc)* using passport and it works perfectly fine. But i want to save the social login credentials in Database *(i am using mongoose)* *(which is ofcourse in/on the backend server)*
and my Passport application is on the frontend *(express)*

**Also** all the **CRUD** operation(s) i perform from **webpage** works like a charm

I am using request module in frontend to send http request to the backend server

Now what i am doing is

**Frontend Server**-

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.FB_CLIENT_ID || 'its a secret',
    clientSecret: process.env.FB_CLIENT_SECRET || 'its a secret',
    callbackURL: `${process.env.BASE_URL}/auth/callback/facebook` || '/auth/callback/facebook',
    profileFields: ['name', 'email', 'link', 'locale'],
    passReqToCallback: true
},  (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) => {

        const form = new FormData();
        form.append('socialLogin', 'facebook');
        form.append('facebook', profile.id);
        form.append('accessToken', accessToken);
        form.append('avatar', `https://graph.facebook.com/${profile.id}/picture?type=large`);
        form.append('email', profile._json.email);
        form.append('username', `${profile.name.givenName}${profile.name.familyName}`);
        // const option = {
        //     socialLogin: 'facebook',
        //     facebook: profile.id,
        //     tokens: [{
        //         kind: 'facebook',
        //         accessToken
        //     }],
        //     avatar: `https://graph.facebook.com/${profile.id}/picture?type=large`,
        //     email: profile._json.email,
        //     username: `${profile.name.givenName} ${profile.name.familyName}`
        // };
        request({
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            url: process.env.BACKEND_URL + socialRoute + '/facebook',
            // data: option,
            data: form,
            headers: {
                'secret': 'its a secret',
                'authorization': true
            },
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        }, function(error, response, 
            console.log('body', body);
            return cb(error, body);
        });
    }
));
```

*(p.s. i also wanted to show you guys the commented code, i.e. the option variable. even that didnt work)*

**Backend Server**

**Router**

```
const socialLoginCont = require('../controllers/socialLogin.cont');

router.post('/facebook', socialLoginCont.facebook);
```

*(yes i am using the express router)*

**Controller**

```
const formidable = require('formidable');
const User = require('../models/Users');

const facebook = async (req, res, next) => {
    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    return form.parse(req, async (err, fields, files) => {
        res.send('it works from facebook: '+ fields);
    });
}
module.exports = {
   facebook 
   //, and more
}
```

Since all other code in my backend server works fine so i havent added any aditional code, just the part in which i need help

After i click the facebook sign button i get this message in my terminal

```
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Server started on port 8000
body it works facebook: [object object]
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
```

I even tried it using **Postman** and this is the output

```
it works from facebook[object Object]
```

If i Output single field it shows **undefined**
i.e.

```
res.send(fields.socialLogin)
```

If i Output multiple field , it shows **[object object]**

i.e.

```
res.send(fields)
```

Thats it i guess, if you guys dont get it, ill try to add some more code,
 but i hope you get the gist of what i am trying to do

*(I have also searched this kind of answer, but didnt find any)*

**Example**

**What i am trying to do is something like this**

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID: process.env.FACEBOOK_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_SECRET,
  callbackURL: `${process.env.BASE_URL}/auth/facebook/callback`,
  profileFields: ['name', 'email', 'link', 'locale', 'timezone', 'gender'],
  passReqToCallback: true
}, (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
  if (req.user) {
    User.findOne({ facebook: profile.id }, (err, existingUser) => {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (existingUser) {
        req.flash('errors', { msg: 'There is already a Facebook account that belongs to you. Sign in with that account or delete it, then link it with your current account.' });
        done(err);
      } else {
        User.findById(req.user.id, (err, user) => {
          if (err) { return done(err); }
          user.facebook = profile.id;
          user.tokens.push({ kind: 'facebook', accessToken });
          user.profile.name = user.profile.name || `${profile.name.givenName} ${profile.name.familyName}`;
          user.profile.gender = user.profile.gender || profile._json.gender;
          user.profile.picture = user.profile.picture || `https://graph.facebook.com/${profile.id}/picture?type=large`;
          user.save((err) => {
            req.flash('info', { msg: 'Facebook account has been linked.' });
            done(err, user);
          });
        });
      }
    });
  } else {
    User.findOne({ facebook: profile.id }, (err, existingUser) => {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (existingUser) {
        return done(null, existingUser);
      }
      User.findOne({ email: profile._json.email }, (err, existingEmailUser) => {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (existingEmailUser) {
          req.flash('errors', { msg: 'There is already an account using this email address. Sign in to that account and link it with Facebook manually from Account Settings.' });
          done(err);
        } else {
          const user = new User();
          user.email = profile._json.email;
          user.facebook = profile.id;
          user.tokens.push({ kind: 'facebook', accessToken });
          user.profile.name = `${profile.name.givenName} ${profile.name.familyName}`;
          user.profile.gender = profile._json.gender;
          user.profile.picture = `https://graph.facebook.com/${profile.id}/picture?type=large`;
          user.profile.location = (profile._json.location) ? profile._json.location.name : '';
          user.save((err) => {
            done(err, user);
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
}));
```

this is an example from https://github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter where they are storing the credentials to the database *(easy)*

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the correct content type in your code, like 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' in your header, currently you are setting "contentType: false". also check the dataType: 'JSON', remove that if you are unsure about the returning content.
see this link for sample
https://flaviocopes.com/node-http-post/

Comment: No, actually this structure is constant across our website and it works